# Проблема с flat jar - Could not find or load class. Error

Tags: java, maven, jar, build

Пытаюсь собрать запускаемый flat jar с помощью maven, каждый раз натыкаюсь на грабли. Я собрал все то что нагуглил/подсказали в кучу и засунул в корневой pom.xml (в проекте несколько модулей).

Выполнил `maven clean-install`, создался jar файл. Но когда я выполняю `java -jar homework_02-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` , то в консоли падает **Could not find or load class com.App**. Почему так происходит? Я ведь указал в pom'e `<mainClass>com.epam.App</mainClass>`

Если есть мысли, буду очень благодарен за помощь!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ваш fat jar должен собираться в `homework_02-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar`, вы не тот jar запускаете, скорее всего.

Comment: @Sergey Дело в том, что у меня в папке target только один jar - homework_02-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar. А with dependencies отсутствует

Comment: Так вы посмотрите к какой цели-то привязано выполнение плагина. Нужно выполнить `mvn package`, чтобы сборка прошла.

Comment: @Sergey выполнил mvn package, и все равно создается обычный jar. Пробовал менять на <phase>install</phase> и потом maven clean - install и также создается обычный jar без dependencies

Comment: Они оба должны создаваться. Не знаю, почему у вас не работает.